# Hibernate cascade save parent and children - parent key not found

Tags: hibernate

I am using Spring, Hibernate and oracle for a project. The database schema was created manually by running sql script. Everything works fine until I encountered a problem with hibernate one-to-many bidirectional cascade save.

In the parent class (Product.java)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="product",
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
public Set<Picture> getPictures() {
        return pictures;
}

@Transient
public void addPicture(Picture picture) {
    picture.setProduct(this);
    pictures.add(picture);
}
```

In the child class (Picture.java)

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="lse09lse06id")
public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
}
```

"lse09lse06id" is the foreign key column in the child entity table.

In my Controller class:

```
Product product = new Product();
.... (set properties of product)
Picture newPicture = new Picture();
.... (set properties of newPicture)
product.addPicture(newPicture);
productService.addProduct(product);
```

In my ProductService class:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addProduct(Product product) {
    productDAO.addProduct(product);
}
```

In my ProductDAO class:

```
@Override
public void addProduct(Product product) {
    product.setDateCreated(new Date());
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(product);
}
```

Exception thrown when the controller code is executed:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>   Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:
>   Could not execute JDBC batch update;
>   SQL [insert into lse09pictures
>   (lse09content, lse09date_created,
>   lse09date_deleted, lse09date_updated,
>   lse09is_deleted, lse09lse06id,
>   lse09id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?)]; constraint
>   [CSSE3005GG.LSE09PICTURES_FK]; nested
>   exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
>   Could not execute JDBC batch update

One of the nested exception thrown:

> java.sql.BatchUpdateException:
>   ORA-02291: integrity constraint
>   (CSSE3005GG.LSE09PICTURES_FK) violated
>   - parent key not found

Any help would be much appreciated. This problem is really nasty. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Remove `cascade` from the `@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})`. Hibernate gets confused by circular references.

Alternatively, save the `Product` instance (by explicitly calling session.save() on it) before the `Picture` instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried both ways but I still get the same exception when I run the code. As for the alternative you suggested, I modified `ProductDAO` in the following way. 

`@Override
public void addProduct(Product product) {
 product.setDateCreated(new Date());
 Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
 session.save(product);
 for (Picture picture: product.getPictures()) {
  session.save(picture);
 }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Using the Hibernate Cascade classes

- org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade
- org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType

Could you try to rewrite it like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
     CascadeType.MERGE })
public Set<Picture> getPictures() {
    return pictures;
}
```

And

```
@ManyToOne
@Cascade(value = { CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.PERSIST,
     CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name="lse09lse06id")
public Product getProduct() {
    return product;
}
```

After that, call to Hibernate.saveOrUpdate should do what you want.

Cyberax is right, circular references can be confusing for Hibernate. Plus, Cascading removal should be used with care - that is, why I only have used Save,Persist, and Merge.